# Is there a quick way to get data from our applications' plist file?

Tags: xcode, facebook

My facebook APPID, for example, is 123456789

It shows up 3 times in my program

FacebookAppID in plist
one of the url schemes is fb123456789

There is a #define api_key @"115372328641884" somewhere

I think 2 is one too many already

I think rather than doing #define api_key @"115372328641884" I should be able to read my app plist files,. see what exist in the key FacebookAppID and set that up.

Is there a quick way to do so? The name of the plist is not constant. I may change project or target name for example. The facebookAppID may not be the same.

I know some regular way to read from plist in general. But what about the main plist? There has to be easier ways? Does it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [`NSBundle`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSBundle_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSBundle/objectForInfoDictionaryKey%3a):

```
NSString *key = [[NSBundle mainBundle] objectForInfoDictionaryKey:@"FacebookAppID"];
```

Comment: Awesome. This is precisely what I need